# ¿Cómo unir dos listas simplemente enlazadas? | Java

Tags: java, poo

Tengo dos listas simplemente enlazadas conformadas por nodos, una contiene la clase usuario y otra la clase vehículo, con sus respectivos atributos. Necesito unir las dos listas y luego mostrarlas en consola pero sin utilizar el java.util.List, o sea solo con listas y nodos, cómo sería la manera más eficiente de hacerlo? Gracias de antemano.

Ejemplo: Lista 1: 1,2,3,4,5 Lista 2: 6,7,8,9,10 Listas unidas: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

(Pero con los datos correspondiente de cada lista, evidentemente)

Primero tengo estas referencias:

```
int size = 0;
int size2 = 0;
Nodo newNodo = null;
Nodo newNodo2 = null;
Nodo head = null;
Nodo pointer = head;

Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
Vehiculo vehiculo = new Vehiculo();
```

Los métodos para insertar elementos en las listas:

```
public void insertar(String nombre, String cedula, String apto, int edad, String ID) {
    newNodo = new Nodo(nombre, cedula, apto, edad, ID);
    if (head == null) {
        head = newNodo;
    } else {
        pointer = head;
        while (pointer.getNext() != null) {
            pointer = pointer.getNext();
        }
        pointer.setNext(newNodo);
    }
    size++;
}

public void insertarVehiculos(String tipo, String placa){
    newNodo2 = new Nodo(tipo,placa);
    if(head==null){
        head = newNodo2;
    } else{
        pointer = head;
        while(pointer.getNext() != null){
            pointer = pointer.getNext();
        }
        pointer.setNext(newNodo2);
    }
    size2++;
}
```

y los métodos para llenar los datos:

```
public void llenar() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nombre;
    String cedula;
    String apto;
    int edad;
    String ID = "";
    String numeros = "1234567890";

    System.out.println("Digite el nombre: ");
    nombre = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite la cedula: ");
    cedula = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite el apto: ");
    apto = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite la edad: ");
    edad = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        int posicion = random.nextInt(numeros.length());
        char car = numeros.charAt(posicion);
        ID += car;
    }
    System.out.println("ID generado: " + ID);

    insertar(nombre, cedula, apto, edad, ID);
}

public void llenarVehiculos(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String tipo;
    String placa;
    
    System.out.println("Digite el tipo de vehiculo: ");
    tipo = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite la placa del vehiculo: ");
    placa = sc.nextLine();
    
    insertarVehiculos(tipo,placa);
}
```

la clase nodo

```
public class Nodo {

Usuario usuario;
Vehiculo vehiculo;
private Nodo next=null;

public Nodo(String nombre, String cedula, String apto, int edad, String ID) {
    usuario = new Usuario(nombre,cedula,apto,edad,ID);
}

public Nodo(String tipo, String placa){
    vehiculo = new Vehiculo(tipo,placa);
}


 public Nodo() {
}

public Vehiculo getVehiculo() {
    return vehiculo;
}

public void setVehiculo(Vehiculo vehiculo) {
    this.vehiculo = vehiculo;
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public Nodo getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Nodo next) {
    this.next = next;
}
```

}

Comment: Por favor coloca tu clase `Nodo` para que sea más fácil reproducir tu programa

Comment: mmmm... se me ocurre una duda, ya que no lo has subido... ¿tu clase coche y vehículo extienden de Nodo?, porfa, sube esas clases y te podré ayudar, ya que es bastante sencillo si esas dos clases heredan de Nodo

Comment: Hola, ya he subido la clase Nodo, espero su ayuda, muchas gracias! (En las clases usuario y vehiculo simplemente tengo los atributos, sus correspondientes getters and setters y respectivo constructor)

Comment: La forma mas eficiente seria agarrar la cabeza de una de las dos, y añadirla al final de la otra, y listo, tendrias una sola lista con un monton de items. Ahora, si no, tendrias que definir eficiente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomendaría generalizar un poco más tu clase Nodo. Hacerla para cualquier objeto y ya luego puedes parsear el objeto de acuerdo al resultado de `instanceof`.

Es decir, dejar tu clase Nodo para que reciba cualquier objeto. Si fueran objetos heredados de un mismo padre, limitarlo a la clase padre.

```java
import java.util.Objects;

public class Node {
    private Node next = null;
    private final Object obj;

    public Node(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    public Node(Object obj, Node nextElement) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.next = nextElement;
    }

    public Object getElement() {
        return obj;
    }

    public void setNextElement(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node getNextElement() {
        return next;
    }

    /* O si quieres puedes dejar un método dentro de tu nodo, aunque,
    * personalmente yo lo sacaría de la clase */

    public User getUser() {
        Objects.requireNonNull(obj, "This object is null");
        if (obj instanceof User)
            return (User) obj;
        return null;
    }

    public Vehicle getVehicle() {
        Objects.requireNonNull(obj, "This object is null");
        if (obj instanceof Vehicle)
            return (Vehicle) obj;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Y juntar dos listas simplemente enlazadas sólo debes de especificar que el último nodo de la primera apunte a la cabeza de la otra lista.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {

//      Se crea tu primer lista y se guarda en head
        Node head = createUserNode();

//      Se crea un cursor para recorrer esa lista
        Node cursor = head;

//      Se avanza ese cursor hasta la última posición
        while (cursor.next != null) {
            cursor = cursor.getNextElement();
        }

//      Una vez en la última posición, se se indica que el
//      Siguiente elemento es la cabeza de la otra lista
        cursor.next = createVehicleNode();

//      Esto sólo sirve para imprimir la lista
//      En el ejemplo, se debe de tener cuidado que head != null

        cursor = head;
        do {
            System.out.println(cursor.getElement());
            cursor = cursor.getNextElement();
        } while (cursor != null);
    }

//  Se usa para crear un nodo de puros usuarios
    public static Node createUserNode() {
        return new Node(
                new User("Flor", 27),
                new Node(new User("Karla", 19))
        );
    }

//  Se usa para crear un nodo de puros vehículos
    public static Node createVehicleNode() {
        return new Node(
                new Vehicle("Car", "A27B5D"),
                new Node(new Vehicle("Truck", "56GGH7"))
        );
    }

    /* Digamos que tus clases son así */
    private static class Vehicle {
        private String type;
        private String licensePlate;

        public Vehicle(String type, String licensePlate) {
            this.type = type;
            this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Vehicle: " + licensePlate + "; type: " + type;
        }
    }

    private static class User {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        public User(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User: " + name + "; age: " + age;
        }
    }
}
```